# Use of selected_real_kind in a module

Tags: module, fortran, precision

I am declaring, inside a module, a parameter to define the precision for real numbers:

```
integer, parameter :: dp=selected_real_kind(16,100)
```

When I try to use it in the main program, such as: `real(kind=dp) :: d`

I get an error, which is:

```
Error: Name 'dp' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'dp' from module 'mod_bcp'
```

and hence:

```
Error: Symbol 'd' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a normal behavior for Fortran? (I am compiling with gfortran (GCC) 4.9.2 20141029)

Comment: You will need to show us a complete example. See [mcve]. You likely declared `dp` at multiple places.

Comment: Yes, you are right: I have declared dp in two different modules and the main program uses both modules. Thanks for your help!